# How to import and exclude a JavaScript code dynamically?

Tags: javascript, import

I know my request is very specific, but I am working on a project where I need to import a JavaScript code using a JavaScript file and then exclude it.
An example will be more meaningful than an explanation :

```js
// Import code
let script = document.createElement('script');
    script.id = 'newScript'
    script.innerHTML = "class system { static test() { console.log('Hello World !'); } }";
document.body.appendChild(script);
// Call the function of the imported code
system.test(); // Return "Hello World !" in console
// Exclude code
document.body.removeChild(script);
// Call the function of the imported code. Is supposed to make an error because the code is excluded.
system.test(); // Return "Hello World !" in console
```

I wish the `system.test()` function was no longer available after excluding the file, but it still works.

Thank you in advance for your help!

Answer (score 0):

You cannot unload js once loaded but you can overwrite object.
`system=undefined;`

```js
// Import code
let script = document.createElement('script');
    script.id = 'newScript'
    script.innerHTML = "class system { static test() { console.log('Hello World !'); } }";
document.body.appendChild(script);
// Call the function of the imported code
system.test(); // Return "Hello World !" in console
// Exclude code
document.body.removeChild(script);
system=undefined;
// Call the function of the imported code. Is supposed to make an error because the code is excluded.
system.test(); // Return "Hello World !" in console
```

Comment: I forgot to specify that, for very specific reasons and too long to explain, I would not know the content of the imported code, so I cannot predict which variables or functions it will contain.
Thanks anyway!